# Average Rectangle of a point list

Tags: algorithm, 2d

Right, first off let me give some context. Hopefully my explanation isn't too confusing.

I'm using a face detection algorithm, which returns a rectangle representing the face's bounds within a live video stream. This returns a rectangle once per frame (if there was a face detected).

In any case, what I'm trying to do is get a rectangle that represents the average area within which the face in question has been moving. I keep a list of these rectangles from which I'm attempting to calculate the said average.

I've attempted to calculate a simple average rectangle by averaging all x,y,widths and heights, but the resulting rectangle from this method gets gradually worse the longer the 'face' stays more or less in the same place.

My latest attempt was to get a rectangle from the list of centerpoints for each face, but this is badly skewed when a single face position is near the edge of the image.

Anyway, what I'm hoping to get by posting here is maybe suggestions for an algorithm that already exists that might be able to help with this issue. I've been trying to look up weighted averages but I'm not entirely sure what to look for. Any help would be much appreciated.

What a set of rectangles usually looks like:

[image]

What I'd like to get (the green rectangle):

[image]

Comment: I think you need to better define what you mean by 'average rectangle'

Comment: @StevenMills can you give an image with rectangles u constructed highlighted in it so that we would better analyse

Comment: I've added a couple of photos which might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My latest attempt was to get a rectangle from the list of centerpoints for each face, but this is badly skewed when a single face position is near the edge of the image."

This is the right line of thought to go on, but you want to look into the mathematics of averages. One extreme value is going to throw the results off. You probably want to do something like excluding values outside the IQR (http://www.mathwords.com/o/outlier.htm). This should help you achieve what you're after.

Comment: This seems like the right track. It seems promising from a quick trial.

Answer (score 1):

From your example pictures what you want is not really an average (since it's width and height is larger than all the given rectangles) but a rectangle that bounds all the given face position rectangles excluding some outliers where I'll define outliers as rectangles that don't overlap any other rectangles in the list. My approach to this would be to first find all the outliers and exclude them from the list, then create a rectangle to bound all the others using the highest and lowest x and y coordinates remaining in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider computing a probability distribution of the rectangle centers in both the X and Y direction.  Using something like the numpy percentile method you can decide upon the probability range for your average rectangle.  This will account for the full range of distributions of centers.  Assuming that your rectangles all have the same area, you can create your average rectangle with a buffer if needed.

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
x_buffer=5
y_buffer=10
x_centers=np.random.rand(100)*100
y_centers=np.random.rand(100)*100
xleft=np.percentile(x_centers,30)-x_buffer
xright=np.percentile(x_centers,70)+x_buffer
ybottom=np.percentile(y_centers,30)-y_buffer
ytop=np.percentile(y_centers,70)+y_buffer
Average_rectangle=Polygon([(xleft,ytop),(xright,ytop),(xright,ybottom),(xleft,ybottom)])
Average_rectangle
```